# how to prevent (programmatically) a java application from starting if it's not in a pre-defined directory?

Tags: java

how to prevent (programmatically) a java application from starting if it's not in a predefined directory?

Example:

I have application.jar and I want to make it runnable only if it's located in             "C:\runnable" directory else the application will exit.

any ideas?

Comment: *'I want to make it runnable only if it's located in "C:\runnable"'*  So you want this to run only on Windows machines?  What is the purpose of this extraordinary (silly) requirement?  *"any ideas?"*  Put aside the strategy you intend using to achieve the goal, and describe the goal.

Comment: It's just An example. I'm no't even trying to make any applications, I never say my ideas to public.

Comment: *"It's just An example"*  A poor one, since it failed to communicate the goal.  *"I never say my ideas to public."*  (Rolls eyes.)  If your idea has any value, it will be stolen within 24 hrs of becoming public, even without reverse engineering (e.g. de-compiling) the code.

Comment: _"A poor one, since it failed to communicate the goal"_ Wrong! since "Radu C" gave me the perfect answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
System.getProperty("user.dir").equals("C:\\runnable")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 final String classLocation = GetClassLocation.class.getName().replace('.', '/') 
  + ".class";
```

-> http://www.roseindia.net/java/java-get-example/get-class-location.shtml

Answer (score 1):

Can also Try -

```
    System.out.println(new File (".").getCanonicalPath()); // Current Path
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir")); // Path from where java is executed
```

Answer (score 0):

If the actual criteria is whether the *jar* file is in a given location, you cannot rely on system properties, but must ask the JVM about the location of the jar file and then react accordingly.

See [Determine location of a java class loaded by Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127166/determine-location-of-a-java-class-loaded-by-matlab) for instructions about how to determine the location of the byte code for a given class.  Then do it for a class  you know to be in the jar, and go on from there.